# beamer title bar

Tags: beamer, presentations

can you help me?

How can I remove the title bar and put a title without the bar? please, help me[image]

Comment: I am using madrid theme, but I dont need to title bar

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a minimal example that generates the screenshot and use the edit button (found bottom left corner of the question to edit your question).

Comment: Hello this comand eliminate all bars on all slides but I need to remove the title bar in the principal slide in others not.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add

`\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=transparent}`

or

`\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=transparent, fg=red}`

to specify the text colour to hide the title background. However, this will also hide the title backgrounds for all other frames. The fix is to also add:

`\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{ bg=beamer@blendedblue, fg=green}`.

The colour `beamer@blendedblue` is the default colour used in beamer. You can change it to whatever you would like, such as `bg=yellow` instead. The way to change the colour of the lower bar is by using:

`\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=green, fg=orange}    %left palette`
`\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=yellow, fg=blue}      %middle palette`
`\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=red, fg=black}         %right palette`

The output is as follows:

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=transparent, fg=red}       %hides title
                                                             %background (first page only)
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=green, fg=orange}      %left palette
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=yellow, fg=blue}        %middle palette
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=red, fg=black}           %right palette
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{ bg=beamer@blendedblue, fg=green}%adds beamer blue background
                                                             %to the title for 2nd and 
                                                             %above slides.

\title[Title]{Title}
\author{Name}
\institute{University name}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
    \frame{\titlepage}
    \begin{frame}{The Title of the Slide}
        Some text!
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Love you! thanks

Comment: and how I can change the color letter in this slide for white? title and name, university, etc.

Comment: @julianaperezordoñez so you want the text in the lower bar changed from white to something else?

Comment: yes! I want to do this

Comment: Hello this comand eliminate all bars on all slides but I need to remove the title bar in the principal slide in others not.

Comment: Hello this comand eliminate all bars on all slides but I need to remove the title bar in the principal slide in others not.

Comment: @julianaperezordoñez Please update your question so that it is better understood.

Comment: @julianaperezordoñez, I have updated the text colour request. You see, it would have been much easier for you and us if you updated the question, as AndreC suggested. You would also attract more people to help you out since they know exactly what you want.